# Loading (Large) R Script File

Tags: r

Good Morning.

I am new to R.

Need to load a 4.5MB sized R script file using RStudio (ver. 3.0.2). Unfortunately it returns an error as the image below,

[image]

[image]

Apparently the max script file size is 2MB.

Is there a way to load what considered large script file by R Studio without dividing it into 3 different script files?

I am exploring if there is a place in Global Setting which have set the script max file size to be 2MB but did not find the parameter settings there.

Hope you can guide.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say script, you mean source code? Can you open it up in a text editor?

Comment: Yes I have no problem opening it in a text editor on several computers. Its a R Script file that ends with .R extension. Can also be said a source code file

Comment: Try opening it in Rgui. (I'm impressed that you have a 4.5 MB script. That much source code should be in a package.)

Comment: Yeah, there's something seriously wrong with whoever wrote that script.  Send it back (I'm not kidding) and tell him to learn to write functions and packages; to separate data from functions, and so on.  A script even 10% as big as this one would be impossible to validate or debug.

Comment: Oh, and BTW   never **EVER** believe a filetype based solely on its extension.  While `R` will attempt to execute whatever's  inside a `foo.R` file, that doesn't mean the contents are valid, let along being commands and/or functions that you actually want to `source` every time.

Comment: While RStudio may not let you open a source file this size, can you open it in a text editor, copy the contents, and paste the contents into the Source pane of RStudio?

Comment: Thought I was able to open it in text editor, unable to copy and paste it directly to the RStudio. It hangs the RStudio probably due to huge memory needed. I have created and opened an empty file with .R extension on a text editor and also on RStudio. I have cut and paste the content of my file (4.5MB) to this empty file and save it. The same file which was opened in RStudio auto refresh it with new content. As you correctly mentioned, this is ridiculous, working to convert it using functions rather static lines. Thanks for all the pointers. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I can open in RGUI and execute it. Have reworked the R script given to me. Many lines repeated with different combination of options using variables <- c('Option1', 'Option2', ...). Have done a dynamic script with less than 300 lines!